# How to remove this huge distance between label and input in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds, lwc-dom

How to remove this huge distance between label and input in LWC. I didn't use custom styles, only from the salesforce lightning design system.

Here's my code from the HTML file:

```
<div>
        <template if:true={locatedOnTab}>
            <lightning-input type="text" name="Page number" label="Now page number" value={nowPageNumber} variant="label-inline" readonly></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Previous" title="PreviousPageButton" onclick={handlePaginationClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={previousButtonDisabled}></lightning-button>
            <!--I think this code is not important--!>
        </template>
    </div>
```

Here's what I get :
[image: Here's what I get]

here's what I want to get (roughly) :
[image: here's what I want to get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `label-hidden` variant, define your own div for the label and put both elements (label and lightning-input) in a flex box:

```html
<template if:true={locatedOnTab}>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
        <div class="slds-form-element__label">Now page number</div>
        <lightning-input type="number" name="Page number" label="Now page number" value={nowPageNumber} variant="label-hidden" read-only></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Previous" title="PreviousPageButton" onclick={handlePaginationClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={previousButtonDisabled}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

By the way, `readonly` is wrong, the right attribute is `read-only`. [Specifications](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification)
I also changed the type of lightning-input to `number`.

However if you don't need a lightning-input, you could also change it to:

```html
<template if:true={locatedOnTab}>
    <div>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Now page number</span> {nowPageNumber}
    </div>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Previous" title="PreviousPageButton" onclick={handlePaginationClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={previousButtonDisabled}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm using the first option, thanks